# IIFE in JS using for fetch data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function, which would be pull data in array, and then print them into condole. For right work `for` loop i'm using IIFE function for retrive all data consistently, but code not work correctly. Result is empty array: `[]`. I think that my trouble due to the incorrect IIFE which i made. How I can fix this bug?

```
var url = [
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cevhxOsZnS',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguaPsRxAi',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm'
]

function fetchData(arg) {
  var urls = Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [...arguments]
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; urls.length < i; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      fetch(urls[i])
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => arr.push(res))
    })(i)
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(fetchData(...url))   // printed empty array: []
```

Comment: The problem is that fetch is *asynchronous*, so you are returning your array before any of the fetches have finished. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) may help.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That's right, fetch is asynchronous and for fix this feature i'm using IIFE function. And now I don't understand why it's not work correctly.

Comment: Your IIFE is working fine. What is not working is that you are doing `console.log` before the results are fetched (remember? fetch is asynchronous, your code keeps running while the data is fetched)

Comment: Of course! My fault, sorry. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Here is how I would do it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyQrNd?editors=0010#0

Comment: Your loop condition `urls.length < i` seems backwards.